# x.docx and x.txt are very large and would not open

Tags: matlab

I have this code:

```
filename = 'x.docx';    
nc=2500;    
A=zeros(1,nc);    
matObj = fopen(filename,'w');    
n = 2500*50;    
for k=1:n    
    fprintf(matObj, '% f', A);    
    fprintf(matObj, '%\n', A);    
end
```

But `x.docx` becomes very large (2.61G) and would not open.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Why not write in a `.txt` file. There are softwares to open even 5GB of text files.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. If you wish to export data to microsoft format files, why don't you try [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)?
2. Your `fprintf` commands a bit strange, what is `'%\n'`?
   How many spaces do you want in the formatting of `'% f'` ?
   Try looking at [string formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) for more concrete examples.
3. You **must** close the file `fclose( matObj );` when you're done.
4. Your code writes `n` (125,000) lines with 2500 zeros in each this alone is ~125 MILLION characters. So, 2.6 GB file is not too far from what you actually writes...